# aerokube moon is starting only 1 session of chrome after updating java17 and selenide 6.15

Tags: java-17, selenide, aerokube-moon

aerokube moon is starting only 1 session of chrome after updating java17 and selenide 6.15

Moon version 1.6.0 and Pods set is 4.  How to start multiple sessions of chrome with moon ?